# Autotest stalls when launched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autotest

I'm trying to get a Rails (version 2.3.5) app set up to run RSpec and Autotest.

I've got both `rspec` (1.2.9) and `rspec-rails` (1.2.9) vendored as plugins in the app. I then have ZenTest 4.4.0, Autotest (4.3.2) and Autotest Rails (4.1.0) gems installed.

Whenever I run the `autotest` command in the app, all I get is this:

```
loading autotest/rails
style: Rails
```

And then it just sits there and never actually runs any of the test.

Comment: same problem except in Rails 3

Comment: solved mine actually -- had the autotest/discover.rb file named as autotest/discover.rb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `autospec` instead of `autotest`

Comment: Note that `autospec` is gone in RSpec 2.  But for RSpec 1, this is correct.